# Apache Spark select columns from nested arrays in json

Tags: c#, json, apache-spark

I have Apache Spark and application in C#. My json structure is like:

```
  { 
    "jobId": 207,
    "jobName": "Jan18-Test10",
    "files":
    {
        "file": [
            {
                "fileId": 297,
                "jobId": 207,
                "fileName": "test job",
                "partsfiles":
                {
                     "partsfile":
                    [
                        { 
                            "partFileId": 99,
                            "fileId": 777,
                            "partFileName": "first part"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to select three columns, jobName, fileName, partFileName
In C# I have code:

```
 var dataFrame = spark.Read().Option("multiline", "true").Json("mySparkDir/table1/job1.json");
dataFrame.Select("jobName", "files.fileName", "files.partsfile.partFileName").Show();
```

It doesn't work.
It works when I have only property with array nested one level:

```
dataFrame.Select("jobName", "files.fileName").Show();
```

Error that occurs when I have 3 parameteres:

```
[Exception] [JvmBridge] JVM method execution failed: Nonstatic method 'select' failed for class '9' when called with 2 arguments ([Index=1, Type=String, Value=jobName], [Index=2, Type=String[], Value=System.String[]], )
   at Microsoft.Spark.Interop.Ipc.JvmBridge.CallJavaMethod(Boolean isStatic, Object classNameOrJvmObjectReference, String methodName, Object[] args)
Unhandled exception. System.Exception: JVM method execution failed: Nonstatic method 'select' failed for class '9' when called with 2 arguments ([Index=1, Type=String, Value=jobName], [Index=2, Type=String[], Value=System.String[]], )
 ---> Microsoft.Spark.JvmException: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`files`.`partsfile`['partFileName']' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires integral type, however, ''partFileName'' is of string type.;;
```

---

I corrected json a little. This is print scheme result:

```
root
 |-- files: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- file: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- fileId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- fileName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- jobId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- partsfiles: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- partsfile: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- fileId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- partFileId: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- partFileName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- jobId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- jobName: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `dataFrame.PrintSchema();`

Comment: I corrected json to right structure and print schema